# Complex Hieraechical Traversing inside Case statement T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to write a complex `CASE` statement on a hierarchical data set.

This is the table with sample data:

```
Level  Parent     Child       IsDirector
----------------------------------------
0      NULL       SteveJobs     NO
1      SteveJobs  TimCook       YES
2      TimCook    Greg          NO
3      Greg       Mark          NO
4      Mark       Jack          NO
4      Mark       Kim           NO
4      Mark       Tyler         NO
4      Mark       Emma          NO
```

I'm trying to write a SQL query to find the director of a person. The result is supposed to be like this if I query for Kim.

```
Parent  Child   Director    
-------------------------
Mark    Kim     TimCook
```

Here is the query that I wrote.

```
SELECT 
    A.Parent, A.Child,
    CASE A.IsDirector 
        WHEN 'YES' 
           THEN A.Child
        WHEN 'NO' 
           THEN CASE 
                   WHEN (A.IsDirector = 'NO' AND A.Parent IS NOT NULL) 
                      THEN A.Parent
                      ELSE (SELECT  
                                CASE WHEN B.IsDirector = 'YES' 
                                        THEN B.Parent
                                END AS Director
                            FROM @Org B 
                            WHERE B.Child = A.Parent) 
                END 
    END AS Director,
    A.IsDirector
FROM
    @Org A
WHERE 
    Child = 'Kim'
```

The result is

```
Parent  Child   Director  IsDirector
------------------------------------
Mark    Kim     Mark      NO
```

Below is the SQL Fiddle. Sorry i don't know how to format the above codes.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b5830

Comment: So the director is always the record above the parent?  Better question: what determines "Director"

Comment: anyone can be a Director but the Director will always be a child of a Parent who has no parent. In the above table that i provided, there can be an another record as Level 1. Simple answer: Level 1 will always be a director and Level 0 will never have a parent. Please let me know if this answers your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps with a recursive cte

```
Declare @YourTable table (Level int,Parent varchar(50),Child varchar(50),IsDirector varchar(50))
Insert into @YourTable values
(0,NULL,'SteveJobs','NO'),
(1,'SteveJobs','TimCook','YES'),
(2,'TimCook','Greg','NO'),
(3,'Greg','Mark','NO'),
(4,'Mark','Jack','NO'),
(4,'Mark','Kim','NO'),
(4,'Mark','Tyler','NO'),
(4,'Mark','Emma','NO')

Declare @Fetch varchar(50)='Kim'

;with cteHB as (
      Select Child
            ,Parent
            ,Lvl=1
            ,Director=case when IsDirector='Yes' then Child else '' end
      From   @YourTable 
      Where  Child=@Fetch
      Union  All
      Select R.Child
            ,R.Parent
            ,P.Lvl+1
            ,Director=case when IsDirector='Yes' then R.Child else '' end
      From   @YourTable R
      Join   cteHB P on P.Parent = R.Child)
Select A.*
      ,B.Director
 From  @YourTable A
 Join  cteHB B on (A.Child=@Fetch and Director<>'')
```

Returns

```
Level   Parent  Child   IsDirector  Director
4       Mark    Kim     NO          TimCook
```

Just for fun, to see the path, you could replace the file SELECT with

```
Select Lvl = Row_Number() over (Order By Lvl Desc)
      ,Child
      ,Parent
      ,Director
From cteHB
Order By 1
```

Comment: Looks like this is the most effective method. I haven't tried this on my real life scenario. will try this and let you know if this work. BTW, how can i endorse you or something ? I really like your prompt and effective reply.

Comment: @gopinath A simple thanks is more than I need.  Cheers

Comment: I tried this code and it works fine when i query for a particular child. However I want to customize this very code to do a Select * from cteHB to display a result of Parent Child Director. I don't care about Lvl but it's good to have it though. I tried removing the variable and the where clause but couldn't get the expected result